# IFNULL returns nothing rather than 0, any way to make this work?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am working on a query to calculate a percentage of users who had to wait more than 30 minutes. The outer query selects the type of users (there are 6 types) and the total count of users (grouped by their user_type) from the last 30 days.

The subquery is meant to return a count of all users who had to wait more than 30 minutes.

The problem I am running into is that depending on the clinic, sometimes no users had to wait more than 30 minutes, so I will be missing rows, and mysql will just endlessly try to execute the query

I tried using COALESCE and IFNULL, but they are not returning 0 as I would like because I also need to use a GROUP BY in order to keep the rows separated

Is there another way to have a row that has no results return a 0 rather than just being excluded entirely?

This is my query:

```
SELECT
user_type,
count(user_type) total_users,
        (SELECT
        count(user_type)
        FROM
        my_clinic
        WHERE Appt_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
        AND clinic = 'Baseball'
        AND wait_time > 30
        GROUP BY user_type) as total_over_thirty
FROM
my_clinic
WHERE Appt_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
AND clinic = 'Baseball'
GROUP BY user_type
```

Expected Output should look something like this

```
user_type total_users total_over_thirty
type1        300           25
type2        400           45
type3        600           15
type4        250           45
type5        300           15
type6        300           28
```

But when there are 0 users who waited less than 30 minutes for a particular user_type, you get a row mismatch and it throws a wrench in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the query without the subquery:

```
SELECT
  user_type,
  count(user_type) total_users,
  sum(if (wait_time>30, 1, 0)) as total_over_thirty
FROM my_clinic
WHERE Appt_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() AND clinic = 'Baseball'
GROUP BY user_type
```

Comment: Thank you, was unaware that would be syntactically acceptable